# Vim inside Tmux: <C-w>l (swapping between vim splits) enters ^]lfilename^] into vim

Tags: vim, tmux

If I have vim open inside tmux, when I navigate between vim splits (not tmux tabs or vim tabs) in the split I just navigated away from, I get the following entered as if it was text in the file: `^]k<filename>^]`. This text appears on the line I just left. `<C-w>l|k|j|h` all have this affect. Additionally, when I use `:tabn` or `:tabp`, the command line in vim is filled with the same text. It disappears if I move the window, so I know its not actually modifying the file, but it is annoying to see it all over my screen.

Has anyone seen this happen to them before, or know how to fix it?

Comment: What is the TERM variable inside of tmux. It should be screen or screen-256color

Comment: setting `export TERM=screen-256color` seems to have fixed it. Thanks! If you submit this as an answer I can accept it as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your TERM variable is set improperly. It should be set to either screen or screen-256color.