# Conflict between tab to insert spaces and superTab

Tags: vim

I have conflict right now so that whenever I want to insert a tab (2 spaces since I have `set expandtab` in .vimrc) I get list options. Currently Im trying to make a mapping

`inoremap <C-tab> <C-v-tab>`

But this does not work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's not a very good idea to remap `<c-v>` as that starts visual block mode.

Comment: Please do not set your indent settings in your `~/.vimrc` (actually any buffer local settings). [Vim settings constantly getting reset](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25898409/438329)

Comment: What does `<c-v-tab>` mean? Control + `v` + tab? The `v` key and the `tab` key are not keyboard modifiers

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have an alternative mapping for the `<Tab>` key, that's

```
inoremap <C-Tab> <Tab>
```

The `noremap` part automatically ensures that SuperTab's mappings don't apply, and you get the built-in functionality.

Yours didn't work because of the invalid key notation, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> followed by <kbd>Tab</kbd> would be (here with `:imap` to offer a worse alternative):

```
imap <C-Tab> <C-v><Tab>
```